# R DataTable: How to format a column to show numbers with comma for thousends?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Inside Shiny, I'm rendering a data table.

I was reading the options for the DT package, and I'm founding that to do this I need to know Javascript.

https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html

```
m = as.data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(100, 1e5, 1e6)), 20))
datatable(m, options = list(
  rowCallback = JS(
    "function(row, data) {",
    "var num = '$' + data[3].toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ',');",
    "$('td:eq(3)', row).html(num);",
    "}")
), callback = JS("table.order([3, 'asc']).draw();"))
```

I don't know a lot about JS, so I'm asking this question. My biggest number right now is: 22381, and lowest 0.

**I would like to display: 22381 as 22,381. If posible: 22381 as S/.22,381.**

This is how my DataTable is rendering rightnow, I'm using the options to order (desc) the revenue.

```
output$products <- renderDataTable(products_ss(),
                                           options = list(
                                             order = list(list(2, 'desc'))
                                           ))
```

**UPDATE 1: How to apply `formatCurrency`?**

Applying it like this gives error:

*You specified the columns: itemRevenue, but the column names of the data are*

```
output$productos_sams <- renderDataTable(productos_samsung()  %>% 
                                         formatCurrency(c('itemRevenue'), currency = ' S/.',
                                                        interval = 3, mark = ',', before = FALSE),
                                       options = list(
                                         order = list(list(2, 'desc'))
                                       ))
```

I've changed your answer to match my column name.

Comment: An option without Javascript might be converting the column to a character that is formatted using `scales::comma()`
`> scales::comma(22381)`
`[1] "22,381"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `DT::formatCurrency`

```
library(DT)
datatable(m) %>% 
             formatCurrency(c('V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5'), currency = ' S/.',
                            interval = 3, mark = ',', before = FALSE)
```

## Update1:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
#Use DT::dataTableOutput and DT::renderDataTable as shiny also has these functions name
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    m <- reactive({m <- as.data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(100, 1e5, 1e6)), 20))})
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      datatable(m()) %>% formatCurrency(c('V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5'), currency = ' S/.',
                                           interval = 3, mark = ',', before = FALSE) 
    )
  }
)
```

As in https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html *The first argument of DT::renderDT() can be either a data object or a table widget returned by datatable(). The latter form can be useful when you want to manipulate the widget before rendering it in Shiny, e.g. you may apply a formatting function to a table widget:*. So you need to `datatable(m())` before passing it to another step.

Comment: Ty, I've tried you answer but it's giving me an error, see my update. May you explain how to apply `formatCurrency` inside a shiny render function?

Comment: Maybe you could help also to answer this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642515/shiny-datatable-formatcurrency

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected. But now I've lost the descending order for the 2nd column. I don't know how to %>% pipe that option in the options list. May you extend that part, plese.